# RTE 2501 when using OutputTo to save to a SharePoint 2010 document library, but works fine when saving to local HDD

Tags: vba, sharepoint-2010, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access 2010 databases that creates a PDF and then saves the file to a SharePoint 2010 document library.  This had been working fine for a couple of years, but now I am getting a 2501 Run-time Error "The OutputTo action was canceled."

I can change the save path to the local HDD and it works fine.  The error only occurs when I try to save the file to the SharePoint document library.  If I change the OutputFormat to something other than acFormatPDF, the error message is no longer displayed, but still no file is written to the SharePoint document library.

I am the SharePoint site owner, so permission is not an issue.

```
Const rootPath As String = "https://www.thisisnotreallythesharepointurl.com/"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Participant Certificate", acViewPreview, , strWhereCond, acWindowNormal

strReportName = strViewCity & "_" & strViewState & "_" & strLastname & "_" & strFirstname & ".pdf"
myPath = rootPath & strYear & "/Participant_Certificates/" & strReportName

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath

DoCmd.Close acReport, "Participant Certificate"
```